# Using regex or sub how can i remove any string between any character and a whitespace in a sentence?

Tags: regex, r, whitespace

I have a lot of strings that have a special symbol e.g. "~" and then followed by latin letters and then by space " ":

```
x <- c('~yesicametoyour home tonight.', 'yes~iknow this fact for sure,')
```

1) ~yesicametoyour home tonight.

2) yes~iknow this fact for sure,

I want to remove any character between this "~" and the 1st whitespace that exists after that character.

The result must be

1)  home tonight.

2) yes this fact for sure,

```
gsub( "(@.*[[:space:]]),", "aaaaaaaaaa", df5)
```

Comment: `trimws(gsub('~\\w+', '', x))` or `gsub('^~\\w+ |~\\w+', '', x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option that only uses `gsub` (effect of `trimws` performed manually).

```
x <- c('~yesicametoyour home tonight.', 'yes~iknow this fact for sure,')

gsub("(^ | $)", "",      ## (2) replace a space at the start or end with nothing
  gsub("~[^ ]*", "", x)  ## (1) replace pattern ~[everything up to a space] with nothing
)
[1] "home tonight."           "yes this fact for sure,"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to match `~` and then any one or more character(s) other than whitespace (`\S+`).

The pattern is clear: `~\S+`. See [the regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tY6wD3/1).

In R, you may use

```
> trimws(gsub("~\\S+", "", x))
[1] "home tonight."           "yes this fact for sure,"
```

The `trimws` will remove any leading or trailing whitespace remaining after the removal.